# ExtJS How to update filtered store data?

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, grid, store

Just doing these steps:

1. I have grid filled with data from store.
2. I filter it (for example: Show only with status "late").
3. Data in store is updated.
4. I still see filtered old data (old records with status late).
5. I remove filter, All new data appear, with all old records which were not visible during filter.

Maybe someone know why and how to fix this?

**FIXED**
This code in store made a trick:

```
    listeners : {
    beforeload : function() {
        this.data.clear();
        if(this.data._source)
            this.data._source.clear();
    }
},
```

Comment: The data is not disappear from store only filtered, you can see the filters on the store

Comment: problem is that it not changes on update

Comment: What you described is not a problem. you add records to store and then remove the filter, can you be more accurate where is the problem?

Comment: I have data : [a,b,c] after filter is visible [a], I update store so in store data become [f,g,h], but in griid still visible [a], so I remove filter and I see in grid: [b,c,f,g,h].  Problem: [b,c] should not be in store.

Comment: I think we need to see some source code to more accurately help you with this problem

Comment: added code of grid, and store.

Comment: a `filter` just removes records from the store _temporarily_ from view it doesn't remove them permanently.  If you want to remove the records _permanently_ then you need to remove those records from the store.

Comment: I want not only remove this items, also whent store is reloaded with new data, i want to aply same filters to new data.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `yourStore.reload()` to your update event.